# Error when installing Gdebi core

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, debian

I have tried to install the gdebi core in the termial but this comes up: T

```
he following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdebi-core : Depends: python3-debian but it is not going to be installed
 skypeforlinux:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libatk1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.12.4) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libcairo2:amd64 (>= 1.2.4) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libcups2:amd64 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libexpat1:amd64 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libfreetype6:amd64 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libgcc1:amd64 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libgconf-2-4:amd64 (>= 3.2.5) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libnspr4:amd64 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libsecret-1-0:amd64 (>= 0.7) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libv4l-0:amd64 (>= 0.5.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libx11-6:amd64 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libx11-xcb1:amd64 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxcb1:amd64 (>= 1.6) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxcomposite1:amd64 (>= 1:0.3-1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxcursor1:amd64 (> 1.1.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxdamage1:amd64 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxext6:amd64 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxfixes3:amd64 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxi6:amd64 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxrandr2:amd64 (>= 2:1.2.99.3) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxrender1:amd64 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxss1:amd64 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxtst6:amd64 but it is not installable
                       Depends: apt-transport-https:amd64 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libfontconfig1:amd64 (>= 2.11.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libdbus-1-3:amd64 (>= 1.6.18) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libstdc++6:amd64 (>= 4.8.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Before I was trying to install skype but people said that I installed the wrong skype because I didn't have an AMD CPU.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want to install it, not just extract it. I'm sure Googling "how to install a deb file" will give you a million hits. Naturally the deb file needs to be for the Pi.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortuantely you can't run an executable for amd64 on a Raspberry Pi.**
The various errors shown by your `dpki -i skypeforlinux-64.deb` coummand tell us you're trying to install the PC (amd64) version of the skype client. This will not work on a Raspberry Pi, because it is a different architecture.

**If you've got an .deb for the Raspberry Pi, here is how to install it:**

`dpgk -i` does not install dependencies automatically. You can either look at the output and install packages by hand (`libasound2`,`libatk1.0-0`, ...).

There is a tool named `gdebi` that can install a `.deb` with it's dependencies, but it must be installed first : `sudo apt-get install gdebi-core`.

Then you can run `sudo gdebi toto.deb` to install `toto.deb`.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

A `.deb` file is actually an `.ar` file with a pair of compressed `.tar` files inside.

```
ar -x whatever.deb
```

You may want to do this in a dedicated directory as the contents do not create one.

The `.tar` files may be a mix of `.xz` or `.gz` encrypted -- or, I suppose, anyone of a number of formats supported by `tar` (see "Compression Options" in `man tar`).  They will be named `control` and `data`.  The former again does not unfold tidily into it's own directory, the latter will create a hierarchy mirroring parts of a normal root filesystem.

```
tar -zxf control.tar.gz
tar -Jxf data.tar.xz
```

The hierarchy will contain files that the `.deb` installs, in the location it would install them.  The control files are a set of scripts used before and after installing, etc.

*However*, as pim points out, inspecting the file won't make it magically work if the binaries use the wrong ISA.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Oh I fixed it with sudo apt-get install -f